# Separate a Table into multiple database Based on a field in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a News Feeds application, that Hundreds user send query to server and get news. For better performance in database connection (more rapid), Is it rational that separate news in multiple database Based on news Type field (total news,province news)?

Comment: No Any suggestion to improve?